# How to multiply any number with decimal number

Tags: arithmetic, mental-arithmetic

I can't remember multiplication tables, is there any math trick for multiplication?

Comment: Do you know how to multiply numbers which are not decimals? Like $23 \times 518$ for example?

Comment: I have difficulty with multiplying or dividing decimal

Comment: Yes, but can you multiply or divide numbers that are not decimals?

Comment: Ya i can multiply those normal  numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you **count** the number of decimals,

Consider $$45.2 \times 2.34$$

You do $$452 \times 234 = 105768$$

Notice how 45.2 has a decimal "one place" to the right, and 2.34 has a decimal "two places" to the right. Adding them up, we get "3 places to the right", for a final answer of $105.768$

Comment: Got the point thank you stack mate

Comment: Good thing I still commented even after  you accepted an answer! No problem!

Answer (score 1):

Just do simple multiplication of numbers and place the decimal on the correct position
 For Example:$$2.3\times5.18$$ Step $1:\text{Simple multiplication}$ $$23\times518=11914$$ Step $2:\text{Place the decimal}$ $$=11.914$$

Comment: Is there any logic behind shifting points

Comment: Where should the decimal be placed? What if both numbers are decimals? Please clarify your answer, thanks!

Comment: I mean what if two ✌ decimals and do a division ➗

Comment: @shardulc Add the number of decimal places together. For example, from the answer above, $2.3$ has $1$ decimal place. $5.18$ has $2$ decimal places. So, the result will have $1+2 = 3$ decimal places. Also see the answer above this one.